# How to replace file-image with url-image in flutter quill

Tags: flutter

I have implemented flutter_quill editor in my mobile application.So I need to upload all images to firebase storage, Which user has picked from the gallery.But this action should do after user creating the whole document.

I use this method to get the json document,

`Future<String> onUpload() async{ return jsonEncode(controller.document.toDelta().toJson()); }`

Then I use this function to upload assets to the firebase storage,

`Future<String?> uploadAssetsToStore({filePath, folderName, fileName}) async{ return await StorageService().uploadFile(filePath, folderName, fileName); }`
`

I need a code to this question which gives the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the solution after little experiment,

```
Future<String> getFinalizedDoc() async{
var jsonPost = jsonDecode(widget.post);
for (var operation in jsonPost){
  if (operation['insert'] is Map && operation['insert'].containsKey('image') && operation['insert']['image'] != "" && !Uri.parse(operation['insert']['image']).isAbsolute) {
    String oldImagePath = await operation['insert']['image'];
    operation['insert']['image'] = await uploadAssetsToStore(
      filePath: File(oldImagePath),
      folderName: 'PostImages',
      fileName: path_delegate.basename(oldImagePath)
    );
  }
  else if (operation['insert'] is Map && operation['insert'].containsKey('video') && operation['insert']['video'] != "" && !Uri.parse(operation['insert']['video']).isAbsolute) {
    String oldVideoPath = await operation['insert']['video'];
    operation['insert']['video'] = await uploadAssetsToStore(
        filePath: File(oldVideoPath),
        folderName: 'PostVideos',
        fileName: path_delegate.basename(oldVideoPath)
    );
  }
}
return jsonEncode(jsonPost);
```

}